# Has there been an end date established for the Maps app on iOS less than iOS 6?

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps

It [has been reported](http://dashes.com/anil/2012/09/who-benefits-from-ios6s-crappy-maps.html) that [the contract between Google and Apple](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2012/09/19/ios-6-maps-dash) to supply maps for iOS has not been renewed (or perhaps already has or is about to expire). Furthermore, it's clear that Google [charges significant amounts of money](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html) for businesses like Apple to use the maps API so it's not clear to me that this data feed can continue to older OS indefinitely.

Has anyone seen a credible announcement if and/or when the map data might stop working for people that choose to stuck with iOS 3, 4 and/or 5 and the Google-data-fed integrated iOS mapping app? (And by choose, I mean the devices are not even supported on iOS 6 so the choice is more to buy new hardware or keep running what you have.)

I'm not looking for an alternative (like running [Google Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8) on iOS 5.1) - just an announced or a real end date of the map tile feed to iOS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that it would continue to work indefinitely.

Comment: I also apologize for the possibility that this will be unanswerable due to the existence of a private deal between Apple and Google but should credible information be out, it would be of great use to have it recorded here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you do not upgrade to iOS 6, you will get to keep the app forever. As for the API not working any more, since Apple used the official API any changes Google makes that would break the old Maps app will also break millions of other apps on many platforms. There is a possibility that Google could revoke Apple's API key, but I seriously doubt that will ever happen.

Answer (score -1):

As numerous news reports said, "if you stay on iOS 5, you can keep Google Maps on your iPhone". And now there's also the Google Maps standalone app for iOS 5.1/6.

Comment: Google Maps (the app) requires iOS 5.1 or newer, so it will even run on older models.

Comment: Thanks - I'm still looking for an end date of the data feed if and when it leaks out or hits us up side the head. :) I'll edit this into the question since it's not clear enough yet.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question; when will the data feed stop working?